# ruby captures method and regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am coming across the [`MatchData#captures`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/MatchData#captures-instance_method) method in Ruby for the first time and wanted to ask if someone could explain it a bit more for me. The Ruby docs say:

> Returns the array of captures; equivalent to `mtch.to_a[1..-1]`.

However I am currently running a regular expression on a long string and it seems to be returning me the last item evaluated? Does this make sense?

this is the string:

```
431cdb7b1ad8183a1434b6d1a407731fac0ea61b8d720d733fefaa77f063df8e vidcoder [23/May/2012:01:17:16 +0000] 76.78.212.49 - B24DEA4883A9FF95 REST.GET.OBJECT accounts/6/videos/xboxcCFC/video.mp4 "GET /accounts/6/videos/xboxcCFC/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 - 2 697898511 56 56 "-" "Apple Mac OS X v10.6.8 CoreMedia v1.0.0.10K549" -
```

this is the regex:

```
line.match(%r{^.*\s+HTTP.*\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+}).captures
```

it returns in this case the number 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only specified one capturing group in your regular expression, it only returns it (as a one-element array containing the "2" string, which is not the same as returning the "2" string directly):

```
line.match(%r{^.*\s+HTTP.*\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+}).captures
=> ["2"]
```

If you try to capture more elements, your array will contains more elements, just as indicated in the documentation:

```
line.match(%r{^.*\s+HTTP(.*)\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+}).captures
=> ["/1.1\" 206", "2"]
```

Comment: ok got it thank you. it seems I need to better understand my regex because that dictates what the captures method will return? I noticed you put (.*) which led to 3 elements being returned

Comment: @BC00 Indeed: Each time you surrounds some part of your regexp with (), it indicates that you wants to capture it for later. You can get more explanations as well as a Ruby regexp tester here: http://www.rubular.com/